# I'm trying to read test score data from a web site

Tags: vb.net, web-services

If I type the URL directly into a browser, it returns the data.
I'm reusing a VB.net program that I've written for a different site, but now I'm getting:

> Access denied: wrong3 HTTP header from

```
Dim WebReq As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest)

'If required by the server, set the credentials.
WebReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

'Get the Respponse.
Dim WebResp As HttpWebResponse = CType(WebReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

'Display the status.
Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusDescription)

' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
Dim ALEKStream As Stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream()

' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
Dim srRead As New StreamReader(ALEKStream)

' Read the content.
Dim responseFromServer As String = srRead.ReadToEnd()
TextBox1.Text = responseFromServer
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the user agent property for the given website you're connecting to. Some servers are set up to reject the request if there is no user agent.

```
WebReq.UserAgent = "TestUserAgent"
```

You may even need to fake the useragent to make it look like it's a browser.

```
WebReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Resources: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx

You may also want to break out fiddler and go to the website via your web browser, then compare what's different between what happens when you go there on you browser vs when this application calls it.

[fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this